# Checking whether a user has posted on a particular post in MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a little social networking app and the user has the ability to 'like' posts that others make.

I can log the likes easily enough, but I want to only do 1 insert per user. At the moment, the same user can 'like' the same post over and over again.

How would I achieve this using MySQL? I'd rather do it in one statement if at all possible.

Here is my current INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO app_likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES ($user_id, $post_id)
```

So basically, I need to check if that user already has an entry in the app_likes table against that post_id.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` condition

```
INSERT INTO app_likes (user_id, post_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT $user_id, $post_id) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT user_id, post_id FROM app_likes WHERE user_id = $user_id AND post_id = $post_id
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, though I get an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id, post_id FROM app_likes WHERE user_id = 6 AND p' at line 1

Comment: @SimonHume try now. I forgot that you can't use VALUES with the `WHERE NOT EXISTS`